# Discord.py int(age).content или str?

Tags: python, discord.py

ошибка:

```
      File "bot.py", line 133, in say
    emb.add_field(name = 'Возраст:', value = age.int, inline = False)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'int'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'int'
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что у строки нет атрибута `int`. Из этого следует, что `age` у вас строка, а у строки действительно нет атрибута `int`. Если вам нужно строку преобразовать к целому числу, используйте `int(age)`. `content` к `int(age)` (как в заголовке вопроса) приписывать не нужно, у целого числа нет такого атрибута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emb.add_field(name = 'Возраст:', value = int(age), inline = False)
```

Хотя я не знаю зачем вам два раза переводить в `int`, если у вас переменная уже имеет тип `int`(если там уже есть число), да и `value` принимает любите значения.

И было б очень хорошо если бы вы еще и код добавили, а не только `Traceback`